# SVG icon is not visible when we are doing enable and disable in IE 11 in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I have one SVG icon which is not visible when we are doing enable and disable in IE. It is working fine in chrome and firefox. Whenever we are loading the page for first time then SVG icon is displaying. After doing some disable and enable mode with some checkbox then it become disappear.

Below html when icon is enabled in IE.

```
<span class="design-icon-right false">
<svg width="20" height="20" fill="#454545" stroke="454545" stroke-width="0" view-box="0 0 64 64">
</span>
```

Below css code when icon is enabled

```
.design-icon-right {
margin-right: 13px;
stroke-width: 0.1;
fill: #747474
}
svg:not(:root) {
overflow: hidden
}
```

Below html when icon is disabled in IE.

```
<span class="design-icon-right true">
<svg width="20" height="20" fill="#454545" stroke="454545" stroke-width="0" view-box="0 0 64 64">
</span>
```

Below css code when icon is disabled

```
.design-icon-right.true svg {
fill: #bdbdbd; // this styling is responsible to make SVG icon in disable mode when some checkbox is click state value got true
}
.design-icon-right {
margin-right: 13px;
stroke-width: 0.1;
}
svg:not(:root) {
overflow: hidden
}
```

This all working fine in chrome and firefox. But having issue in IE. I just need icon to be disabled but in IE it completely disapper.

Comment: Probably not your problem, but you have a typo in your given code: file instead of fill.

Comment: It is fill only. While typing here i did mistake.